# How to add an attachment to an email reply with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

The code below allows me to create an email reply:

```
tell application "Mail"
set theAttachmentFile to "path"

set theMessages to the selected messages of the front message viewer
set theMessage to first item of theMessages
set theOutgoingMessage to reply theMessage with opening window and
reply to all
end tell
```

in this situation I'm not able to add an attachment file to the replay front message. In what way can i do that? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Try, e.g.: `tell content of theMessage to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile} at after last paragraph`

Comment: @CJK, I no longer use Mail or have it setup so as to test with, and why I made the suggestion in a comment. I do have complete tested and working code from when I used to use it, but without being able to test, my first comment to the OP was all I felt I could offer. Any yes that should be `theOutgoingMessage`. :)

Comment: Marco, give @user3439894's suggestion a go because, if it's doable, that would be the way to do it.  However, if I recall, it's not possible to edit an outgoing message created as a reply to another message (a Mail AppleScript bug).  As I don't use Apple _Mail_, I can't easily test it myself.  But, if that attempt doesn't work, I fear there isn't a solution of which I'm aware that will do what you need.  I hope someone proves me wrong and provides you with a working solution.

Comment: @user3439894 I've tested your script but unfortunately it doesn't work. The console log: `missing value` without any error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry no, as I mentioned to CJK, I no longer use Mail or have it setup so as to test with.

Comment: I tried a few things and found out that it is impossible to add any content to a reply-outgoing-message. All `make` calls return `missing value`. Just saying...